# Create a view based on created date filter

Tags: 2013, 2010, view

I want to filter a document library by created date, I want to create a view from `today's date - 20` days only show in view.

normally for example  Today date less than  20/09/2016 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dynamic view by setting it in the view configuration as:

```
Created is greater than or equal to [Today]-20
```

This will always show you files from the past 20 days.

[image]

The way it is worded though, you may want to switch it up to less than or equal to [Today]-20 if you want to see anything older than 20 days. I'm not entirely certian which way you want to go.

Comment: thanks eric i will select Created is greater than or equal to [Today]-20,

Comment: i have any other way to create a view per month basic ,that how many documents per month or any sql query?